# FTP download.file(): error (cannot open URL) and warning (InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The login request was denied)

Tags: r

FTP file download works through browser.
Yet fails with `download.file()`

```
download.file('ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-95/gtf/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.95.gtf.gz', destfile = tempfile())

trying URL 'ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-95/gtf/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.95.gtf.gz'
Error in download.file("ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-95/gtf/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.95.gtf.gz",  : 
cannot open URL 'ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-95/gtf/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.95.gtf.gz'

In addition: Warning message:
In download.file("ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-95/gtf/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.95.gtf.gz",  :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The login request was denied
```

Similar to issue [22721819](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721819/download-file-fails-in-rstudio), but now with a specific warning message (`login request denied`). Solutions proposed there do not work (`Rstudio Tools > Options > Packages > unclick "Use secure download method for HTTP" and "Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP"`)

Any clues? Thankyou for helping :-)