# Getting an error when trying to download a csv

Tags: r, csv, download

Tried the following code.

```
download.file("https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/AAPL/stocks/2020-09-09/2020-10-09", destfile = "./data.csv", method="auto")
```

I keep receiving the error -> Fehler in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

I tried everything suggested to solve that error but i still cant download that file. Hope someone can help thanks in advance.

Comment: My question is related to the following question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64271696/download-csv-file-from-nasdaq-site

Comment: download.file("https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/FMCI/stocks/2020-09-08/2020-10-08", destfile = "./data.csv", method="auto") destfile - you have to use a dot for current dir

Comment: Thanks but i tried it with a dot. Sorry, it was just missing cause of copy paste

Comment: https://support.itrsgroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022122613-What-are-the-common-error-codes-when-monitoring-HTTPS-websites-with-Web-Mon-plugin- You might try to sudo apt (or brew) update / upgrade